# sumar ventas de clientes en cierto año con python

Tags: base-de-datos, pandas, python-3.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un archivo `.CSV` en el cual necesito filtrar por año, `customerID` y `price` para saber cual cliente vendió mas en ese año (2021):

```
with open(datafile, 'r') as fl:
csvreader = csv.reader(fl, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
next(csvreader)
order_list = []

for e in csvreader:
  order_list.append(e)
```

Con este codigo filtre por año y saque un nuevo diccionario con los items que necesitaba:

```
sumas = {}
  for c in order_list:
    if c[2] == '':
      continue
    elif c[0] in sumas.items():
        sumas[c[0].value] += float(c[5])
    else:
      dates = datetime.strptime(c[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
      if dates.year == 2021:
        sumas[c[0]] = float(c[5])
```

Aqui el problema es que me muestra solo 1 cliente por venta y no podria hacer la suma.

Comment: Podés usar un diccionario que tenga de clave el cliente y de valor el total (inicializado en 0). Al recorrer el csv, agregas al diccionario el cliente (si es que no está) y le sumas el nuevo valor obtenido al total que estas armando. Una vez leas todo el csv, tendrás el cliente y el total en un diccionario, y podrás hacer lo que quieras con eso.

Comment: Lo intente asi directamente pero me elimina los elementos repetidos, por ejemplos los id repetidos

Comment: Yo hice mi propuesta en base a que querés agrupar por cliente. Podrías editar la pregunta y aclarar cual es la condición por la que estás agrupando por favor? Por ejemplo, "estoy agrupando según la combinación de cliente y producto"

Comment: debo agrupar por fecha (2021) el cliente (customerID) que hizo mas ventas (sumar los price de esos customerID)

Comment: O sea, querés obtener el cliente que más vendió en 2021, o querés obtener el cliente que más vendió en cada año? Por que si es el primer caso, mi propuesta en el primer comentario debería de servirte.

Comment: sumas = {}

  for c in order_list:

    if c[2] == '':

      continue

    elif c[0] not in sumas.items():

      dates = datetime.strptime(c[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

      if dates.year == 2021:

        sumas[c[0]] = [dates.year, float(c[5])]

Comment: Con ese codigo guarde todo en un diccionario, pero me elimina los ID repetidos

Comment: Buen día @CristianCorredor, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Nota: si usas/deseas usar pandas, es preferible recurrir a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/580388/158880)

---

Una forma de agrupar totales usando un diccionario que agrupa a todos los clientes de un csv (con otro formato, adaptarlo es tarea para la casa) junto a sus totales.

```
import io
import csv

# creamos un objeto archivo en memoria
file = io.StringIO("2021,dante,1\n"
                   "2021,dante,2\n"
                   "2022,juan,1")

reader = csv.reader(file)

totales = {}

for fila in reader:
    anio = int(fila[0])
    cliente = fila[1]
    prec = float(fila[2])

    # si el cliente no está en los totales
    # agregamos el cliente con un total inicial de 0
    if(cliente not in totales):
        totales[cliente] = 0

    # Sumamos el precio obtenido al total obtenido hasta ahora.
    # Nota: si querés un resultado más preciso, que no tenga
    # los problemas de la base 2, te recomiendo usar decimal.Decimal
    totales[cliente] += prec

print(totales)
```

Produce:

```
{'dante': 3.0, 'juan': 1.0}
```

Este código esta destinado puramente a demostrar como se pueden agrupar datos, implementar esto en un csv con un formato distinto al ejemplificado y colocar filtros es tarea para el hogar.

Comment: no funciona... me da un objeto vacio, tampoco haces el filtro por año

Comment: Que raro... podrías editar la pregunta y mostrarme como implementaste esta respuesta por favor? El código de la respuesta está probado y funciona. Además, lee el ultimo parrafo: no hice los filtros por que el objetivo del código es mostrar una forma de agrupar datos. Por eso, el filtro es algo que deberás implementar vos.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En tu pregunta pusiste la etiqueta de `pandas` pero en realidad no aparece por ningún lado en tu código por lo que hago una propuesta con `pandas` suponiendo que en verdad la utilizas en alguna parte.

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

**Nota 2:** Siempre es mejor agregar los datos como texto, aunque sea algunas filas para poder copiar y pegar, cree unos datos ficticios para mostrar el funcionamiento del ejemplo.

Utilizando los siguientes datos:

```
    CustomerID  OrderID                    Date  Price
0            1        1 2021-07-26 14:40:10.521     90
1            2        2 2021-08-08 14:40:10.521     60
2            3        3 2021-07-27 14:40:10.521     90
3            3        3 2021-07-27 14:40:10.521     90
4            4        4 2021-07-28 14:40:10.521    160
5            5        5 2021-07-28 14:40:10.521    125
6            5        5 2021-07-28 14:40:10.521    125
7            6        6 2021-07-28 14:40:10.521    225
8            7        7 2021-08-02 14:40:10.521    100
9            8        8 2021-08-02 14:40:10.521     10
10           8        9 2021-08-02 14:40:10.521      0
11           8        9 2021-08-02 14:40:10.521     70
```

Creamos un `dataframe` en tu caso puedes utilizar [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), yo utilizo `DataFrame` ya que creo los datos directemente en el código.

Luego convertimos la columna "Date" en `datetime64` para poder acceder al año de la fecha utilizando el accesor [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html).

Por último agrupamos por año y por "CustomerID" y solicitamos que de la columna "Price" se cree la suma del grupo

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CustomerID': [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,8],
    'OrderID': [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9],
    'Date': ['2021-07-26 14:40:10.521', '2021-08-08 14:40:10.521', '2021-07-27 14:40:10.521', '2021-07-27 14:40:10.521', '2021-07-28 14:40:10.521', '2021-07-28 14:40:10.521', '2021-07-28 14:40:10.521', '2021-07-28 14:40:10.521', '2021-08-02 14:40:10.521', '2021-08-02 14:40:10.521', '2021-08-02 14:40:10.521', '2021-08-02 14:40:10.521'],
    'Price': [90,60,90,90,160,125,125,225,100,10,0,70],
})

# Convertimos a datetime64
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Imprimimos el dataframe agrupado
print(df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year, 'CustomerID']).agg({'Price': 'sum'}))
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe` agrupado:

```
                 Price
Date CustomerID       
2021 1              90
     2              60
     3             180
     4             160
     5             250
     6             225
     7             100
     8              80
```

En caso de tener más años te daría diferentes grupos por año.

Comment: No me había fijado en eso. Que bueno que te fijaste!

Comment: Es más sencillo con `pandas` xD

Comment: Si, es verdad. Pero como creia que el no usaba pandas, mi respuesta fue orientada a no usar pandas.

Comment: Yo sospecho que no se usa, pero como estaba la etiqueta por eso puse esta opción

Comment: Bueno, no está nada mal ver otras alternativas. Además, uno se divierte dando respuestas. Muchas veces, di respuestas a preguntas donde se respondía con regex sin usar regex.